# Private Ethereum Blockchain Time

Tags: ethereum, private

I want to ask, I have a Private Ethereum Blockchain with Geth and PoA and I have developed a DApp that is connected with a Smart Contract

I don't want to have new empty blocks all the time but only if for example a user add something new to the Smart Contract
The recommended time is 15s from puppeth.
I tried to put to 0s and then indeed I didnt have empty blocks all the time, but I have problem with the blocks, the do not been saved as I expected

Do you have something to suggest?